# How do I make sure an exported pdf only has spreads?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have a book file containing multiple documents. All documents have spreads because the plan is to send all of this to a print shop to make it into a physical book. The problem can be seen on the following picture:

[image: 1]]

Pages 1882 and 1883 are not connected as a spread. This also occurs when a document ends on a single page, and the next document starts with a single page on the right. Now, the reason this is a problem, is because there is still a disconnect when I export the whole book to a pdf:

[image: 2]]

So you get a pdf with mostly spreads, but sometimes single pages in between. I would prefer if I could set a setting to ensure that all the pages are spreads. Is this possible? If no: is this a problem for the print shop or can they still print this as a physical book without any issues?

Comment: I haven't done pre-press, but the printer will probably be imposing the pdf for large sheets, if not then for "printer spreads". Either way, this means a different page order. You might want to draw their attention to the section breaks. The PDF probably only has individual pages anyway: the spreads display is just a viewer preference. Switch to single page view to check if spreads are joined into one logical page.

Comment: I have no experience with working with InDesign *Books*, but I do pre-press and we always want PDFs as single pages because we need to *impose* the pages according to the chosen folding scheme. You hardly ever print the spreads as you see them on screen, so when you export single pages, this shouldn't be a problem. I can see how this is annoying but at least InDesign seems to understand the left and right pages correctly.

Comment: As other's have pointed out, you don't want book documents to merge and create spreads for a PDF.  If it's for print production, you *want* single pages. If it's for onscreen viewing ... you *also* want single pages for easier viewing. I'm afraid you need to explain **why** you want a PDF in spreads. Unless the book is configured for printer imposition  t's unwarranted.. and chances are a printer imposed **book file** is kind of a nightmare use of the Book feature.

Comment: Thank you!! This is very helpful guys

Comment: It is not a problem on this site to come back and answer (and accept your own answer) your own question with a narrative of how it worked out for you.

Comment: I'd also point out that if you output a single page PDF, you can set the **PDF** to **display** spreads by default.